# SVN Checkout of drupal to another site

Tags: svn, drupal, installation, svn-checkout

I'm trying to svn checkout into treeoil.com's public_html directory (site is not really named treeoil.com), but my repo is located on one of my other sites (landonwinters.com). When I try to do this checkout:

```
svn checkout file:///home/landonwinters/svn/treeoil/trunk .
```

But I get an error that reads:

```
svn: Unable to open an ra_local session to URL
svn: Unable to open repository 'file:///home/landonwinters/svn/treeoil/trunk'
svn: Can't open file '/home/landonwinters/svn/treeoil/trunk/format': Permission denied
```

I have the usernames and passwords for both accounts...

Help please :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think your url for the checkout is correct.  You use 'file' when the svn server is local to the same machine, not if it's on another machine altogether.  Perhaps something like `svn checkout http://landonwinters.com/svn/treeoil/trunk`
?